# Are affine morphisms with coherent direct image finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ be a morphsim of Noetherian schemes. I was doing excersise 5.5 of Hartshorn *Algebraic Geometry* and in (c) i showed that finite morphisms preserve coherence (i.e. if $\mathscr{F}$ is coherent on $X$ then $f_*\mathscr{F}$ is coherent on $Y$).

Now I am wondering about something like a converse, suppose we have a morphism $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ of Noetherian schemes with $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ a coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. What conditions de we need on $f$ for it to be finite? (I was thinking maybe about affine morphisms)

Or maybe, a more precise question: are affine morphsims with the condition that $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ coherent, proper? That would work if it is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any proper morphism has the property that $f_*F$ is coherent if $F$ is. So, in particular, they need not be finite. Affine morphism with $f_*O_X$ coherent are proper. Putting these together, a morphism (of reasonable schemes) is finite if and only if it is proper and affine.

Comment: I see, can you explain though why the affine morphisms with coherent $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ are proper?

Comment: @LeLoupSolitaire If $f:\operatorname{Spec} B\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is your morphism (locally this is how an affine morphism looks like), the coherence above is same as saying the map $A\to B$ makes $B$ into a finite $A$-module and thus the map is finite, hence proper.

Comment: Oh I see I see it does make sense indeed thanks... I completely passed near that

Comment: Dear Mohan, I was under the impression that a finite morphism was always equivalent to proper and affine, with no "reasonableness" assumptions. Indeed, a finite morphism is affine by definition, and Corollaire 18.12.4 in EGAIV 4 says that a morphism is finite if and only if it is proper and quasi-finite. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @KReiser  I always worry about lack of some Noetherian hypothesis, so usually add a caveat, just in case.